# VHDL : Not understanding Hierarchical or External Naming or how to use them

Tags: vhdl

*Note: I using quartus ii v13 with vhdl 2008*

I am trying to access the current state of my state machine from inside my test bench file. From my understanding I should be able to do this with External Names, however, I keep getting a syntax error "near text "<"; expecting an identifier, or string literal"

*GFI_entity.vhd*

```
library ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity GFI_entity is
   port (
      CLK            : in  std_logic;   
      my_input1      : in  std_logic;
      my_input2      : in  std_logic;
      RST            : in  std_logic;

      my_output1     : out std_logic;
      my_output2     : out std_logic;
      my_output3     : out std_logic
   );
end GFI_entity;

architecture rtl of GFI_entity is

constant C_2SEC_TC : integer := 127; -- Set this based on clock speed to get desired time 

type machineState is (state1, state2, state3, state4, state5, state6, off_state);

signal currentState, nextstate : MachineState;
signal tmr_cnt  : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); -- time counter
signal tc_2sec  : std_logic := '0'; -- Indicates counter has reached desired time
signal rst_flag : std_logic := '0'; -- Disables RST if test pulse was successful
signal tmr_exp  : std_logic := '0'; -- Latches state of tc_2sec

alias myalias is <<signal .GFI_entity_tb.GFI_entity.currentstate : machinestate>>;

begin

   -- synchronous process for the state machine
   sm_sync_proc: process(CLK, RST, rst_flag, tmr_exp)
   begin
        -- condition for RST to not cause a reset if test was successful or timer expired
        if((rst_flag = '1' or tmr_exp = '1') and RST = '0') then
            currentstate <= off_state;
        elsif(RST = '0' and tmr_exp = '0') then
            currentState <= state1;
        elsif(rising_edge(CLK)) then
            currentState <= nextstate;      
        end if; 
   end process sm_sync_proc;
cominationLogic: process(currentState, nextstate, my_input1, my_input2, tc_2sec, RST, rst_flag)

begin

  case currentState is
    -- Wait for charge up time of all inputs
     when state1 => 
...
```

*GFI_entity._tb.vhd*

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY GFI_entity_tb IS
END GFI_entity_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF GFI_entity_tb IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

COMPONENT GFI_entity
PORT(   my_input1     :   in    std_logic;
        my_input2     :   in    std_logic;
        RST           :   in    std_logic;
        clk           :   in    std_logic;

        my_output1    :  out    std_logic;
        my_output2    :  out    std_logic;
        my_output3    :  out    std_logic

    );
END COMPONENT;

--Inputs
signal my_input1 : std_logic := '0';
signal my_input2 : std_logic := '0';
signal RST       : std_logic := '0';
signal clk       : std_logic := '0'; 

--Outputs
signal my_output1 : std_logic;
signal my_output2 : std_logic;
signal my_output3 : std_logic;
signal count      : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";

--Clock for testing
constant clk_period : time := 2 ms; -- 500Hz

BEGIN
-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT) 
uut: GFI_entity PORT MAP (
     my_input1 => my_input1,
    my_input2 => my_input2,
     RST => RST,
     clk => clk,

     my_output1 => my_output1,
     my_output2 => my_output2,
     my_output3 => my_output3               
              );

 Clk_process: process
    begin
    clk <= '1';
    wait for clk_period/2;
    clk <= '0';
    wait for clk_period/2;
end process;


-- Stimulus process
stim_proc: process
begin   
*do testing here*
```

How can I correctly use External Names here to access my currentstate signal?

The purpose of me wanting to do this is that in my test bench I want to be able to test all possible input conditions at each state, for all my states.

Say im in state2 of my test bench and I want to test a certain input, say input1 = 0 input2 = 1 RST = 0, my state machine should change states. After it does I want to "reset" my current state to be my previous state, state2, so that I can check other possible inputs for state2.

I plan for my test bench to just be a for loop from input1 = 0 input2 = 0 RST = 0 to input1 = 1 input2 = 1 RST = 1, after each iteration of the for loop wait for it to change states, "reset" the current state, and do this 8 times for each state. So that if I have 8 states and 3 inputs it will have tested 64 different combinations. Simply put, I want to test all possible cases.

Maybe theres an easier way to do this? This is my first test bench I've done.

Thanks!

Comment: Is machinestate defined in a package?   If not, then the type will not be known in your testbench.    You have two choices:  1) move machinestate to a package or 2) access an integer equivalent signal - machinestate'pos(stateval)

Answer (score 2):

Two things right off the bat:

- If you want to use `myalias` in the testbench, that's where you need to declare it.
- You need to use instance names in the external name path, not the entity names. For example, `<<signal uut.currentstate : machinestate>>` (path relative to `GFI_entity`).

But I don't see why you're getting that specific error message.

Related question: [How to bring out internal signals of a lower module to a top module in VHDL?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/125710/11683)

Comment: *I don't see why you're getting that specific error message* Quartus II which is VHDL -1993 compatible doesn't support external names, a -2008 feature.

Comment: @user8352 In the settings of Quartus ii I have checked VHDL 2008 under version

Comment: External names aren't synthesis eligible. Don't submit your testbench to synthesis.

Comment: @user8352  Thank you, I did not know that! Do you know the appropriate external path name in my case? Would it be GFI_entity.currentstate as the signal im trying to access is in the GFI_entity architecture?

Comment: The alias must be in the process stim_proc.   Otherwise the design GFI_entity will not have been elaborated yet.   Also note my other comment above about the type not being visible unless you put it in a package or alternately use an integer (machinestate'pos(stateval)